# How to write the concrete type signature of a mapped iter

Tags: rust

In

```rust
fn is_big(a:usize)-> bool { a > 7 }

let numbers:Vec<usize> = vec![1,2,3];
a': {
  let mappeds = numbers.iter().map(is_big);
}
```

How would you write the type signature of mappeds? It's `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'a, usize>, bool, _____>`, I just don't know how to write _____, the concrete type of `is_big`. It would necessarily be impossible if it were a lambda, but it isn't a lambda.

(If you want to know why I need to write such a type signature: I had a trait with an associated `type Iter<'a>: Iterator<Item=&'a V>`. One of the implementors has a very simple `fn iter<'a>(&'a self)-> Self::Iter<'a>` implementation that involves a call to `.map`, I am having no difficulty creating the iterator, but I am having boundless difficulty writing its type for the associated type.)

Comment: If you can restructure your trait to make it possible for `fn iter` to return `impl Iteratior<Item=&'a V>` that will solve type nameability issues.

Comment: How? I tried that, and it seemed that `impl Trait` returns for trait methods aren't possible yet: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65481

Comment: I think both `fn(&usize) -> bool` and `&dyn FnMut(&usize) -> bool` could work, depending on the context.

Comment: At least part of your problem (with the minimal example shown) is that the signature of `is_big` is incorrect - it must accept a borrowed `usize` because it iterates over values stored in the slice, so `map()` receives (and gives out) references. The next issue is that you seem to expect `iter::Map` to have three generic args, where it in fact has two. Once those are fixed, the "obvious" type of `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, usize>, fn(&usize) -> bool>` [compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e72c81d0d5d34c3253af1aae5c72ab9).

Comment: If performance is not paramount, another way to fix the underlying issue is for your trait to return a trait object of type `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = bool>>`. That will allow you to implement the iterator as you wish without having to name its exact type, at the tiny run-time cost of an allocation per iterator, and a pointer-indirection jump per iteration.

Comment: @BallpointBen dyn would work, but I want the concrete type. As it happens, performance is paramount, this is being used in benchmarks.

Your first suggestion worked. I thought the type was going to have to refer to the specific function or something, but I guess not!

Answer (score 1):

The type signature [in that case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f608e8c368d47357b5b5e34e2bd71d62) would be

```rust
std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'a, usize>, fn(&usize)-> bool>
```

Comment: Note this is [`fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) and **not** [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html)